# How can I add properties in WFS layer using OL

Tags: openlayers, wfs

Is there any way I can write in shapefile. As per my knowledge if I load the WFS layer in QGIS and if I have write permission in that layer then I can write in shapefile. Can I add properties in the shapefile using WFS layer using OpenLayers?

My current code is :

```
fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest('AB')),
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (json) {
        console.log(json);
        var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
        //features.set("property", 123);  #Trying to add like this
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
        map.addLayer(vector);
        map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
      });
```

I have done modification in code but its still not working:

```
var pointGML = new ol.format.GML({
        featureNS: 'http://www.openplans.org/uk_portal',
        featureType: ['AB'],
    });
    
    var pointWFS = function(p,f) {
        var formatWFS2 = new ol.format.WFS();
        switch(p) {
            case 'insert':
                node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction([f],null,null,pointGML);
                break;
            case 'update':
                node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,pointGML);
                break;
            case 'delete':
                node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],pointGML);
                break;
        }
        
        var s = new XMLSerializer();
        var str = s.serializeToString(node);
        $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs',{
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'xml',
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'text/xml',
                data: str,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }, error: function(data) {
                    console.error(data);
                }
            }).done();
            
        console.log(" point features were posted to server");
    }
    
    var interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        type: 'Point',
        source: vector.getSource()
    });
    map.addInteraction(interaction);
    interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
        var fea = e.feature;
        pointWFS('insert',e.feature.set('ferrets', 'bar'));
    });
```

I am getting this response:

[image: Response]

Comment: Do you want to write on the server, that is do you want to send a WFS-T request to the server? OL and WFS-T is described somewhat in detail here: https://dbauszus.medium.com/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58 .

Comment: @til_b I have already commented the solution which is there in the provided URL. But I am not able to insert with the following. Can you help me out what I am doing wrong here .

Comment: Sorry, I can only give general tips, I don't know enough WFS-T or geoserver for details. I would try if WFS-T writing is possible from QGIS or from the command line with curl, to see if the server side is working as expected. If that's the case then I would analyse the exact request OL is sending to the server (via the browsers network console) and see if you can spot a difference to your examples that work.

Answer (score 1):

Only Insert / Update / Delete transactions are supported in WFS. You are trying to modify the schema (the one that you can read with DescribeFeatureType request). Same thing than `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN...` in SQL. You cannot do that with WFS.

Excerpt from WFS 1.1.1 standard.

```
12.2.3 <Transaction> element

A <Transaction> element may contain zero or more <Insert>, <Update>,
or <Delete> elements that describe operations to create, modify or
destroy feature instances. A web feature service must process
<Insert>, <Update> and <Delete> elements in the order in which they
are presented in the transaction request. Subsequent update and delete
actions, in a transaction request, may operate on feature instances
created by previous insert actions in the same transaction request2.
An empty <Transaction> element is valid but not very useful.
```